# Unable to view the video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html

while creating a video player using html5 i try to load the video from other source and generated the markup according to it. as shown below

```
var _vid = document.getElementById('vid');
$('#vid').html('<video width=300 height=200 id="vid" controls autoplay src="http://172.16.25.214/gems1_video/30032011.mp4"></video>');
var video = document.getElementById('video');
_vid = $(_vid).find('video').get(0); 
console.info(_vid);
_vid.load();
_vid.play();
```

when i open this file in the local Host it is working fine, but when i hit the url from the other server it shows _vid is a undefined one any idea about it..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making references to elements that have not been created. Also I couldn't get access to the video file.

I re-wrote the sample and linked to a video on my own server, you can see it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/thebeebs/Ye3Nf/

P.S because your code only references mp4 it will only play in IE9, Safari and chrome(although chrome will drop support for H.264 soon). You should add a source of WebM and maybe even ogg too.

Answer (score 0):

```
var _vid = document.getElementById('vid');
```

This should not work until you not created the DOM element. You're trying to get an element that is not exist yet.